# Python - Going over a list of words in python with for loop

Tags: python

Getting back into programming, I've been messing with this for a while now sure it's something super simple or maybe I have things set-up completely wrong.

It's an issue with it not iterating over the rest of the list.

So whenever you run the code you enter a file extension i.e. "File.jpg" and it comes back with image, but if you enter any of the other image types it returns application.

```
def main():
    file = input("File name:")

    extension(file)


def extension(s):
    split = (s.split("."))
    join_s = (''.join(split[1]))
    image_e = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', '.png']

    for i in image_e:
        print(image_e)
        if i == join_s:
            return print("Image/")
        else:
            return print("Application")


main()
```

I haven't got to the part of implementing the application formats just yet, but I am sure once I figure this bit out it shouldn't be any sort of issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your if statement to "if join_s in image_e:" should work. Also,"png" inside image_e should not have a "." infront of it

Comment: Nevermind, yes that was it thank you..., it also makes a lot more sense now visually reading it, I should've attempted that I tried so many different things haha.